# mysql command line: How to make mysql to prompt for username and password?

Tags: mysql, command-line, credentials

To run mysql command line providing a username is:

```
mysql -uUSERNAME ...
```

But how to make the command to prompt/ask for username, so I can omit `-uUSERNAME` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL clients do not prompt for username. If you don't specify a username, it defaults to your shell user (on UNIX/Linux) or 'ODBC' (on Windows). So it says in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html

If you want to omit the user option or the password option, use an options file. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: Doesn't seem the way I will take to go, but thanks for the info anyway